# Window.print() <a href=" ">

Tags: php, веб-программирование

[image: photo]

Когда нажимаю на принт, он у меня делает печать и код. Который написан так

```
<a  href="index.php?page=cart&odd=<?php print $dost['id'];?>" class="count-minus" style="display: block; padding-left:3px; margin:10px; cursor:pointer; font: 15px sans-serif">-</a>
             <input disabled name="amount[<?php print $dost['id'];?>]" type="text" value="<?php  print $dost['amount'] ?>" class="count-input" maxlength="3"  style="text-align:center; width:32px; font: 15px sans-serif; border-radius: 5px;" height:22px; />
            <a href="index.php?page=cart&add=<?php print $dost['id'];?>" class="count-plus" style="display: block; padding-left:1px; margin:10px; cursor:pointer; font: 15px sans-serif">+</a>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы кода там не было?

Comment: где сам скрипт принт ?

Answer (score 1):

Некотрые фреймворки `PHP` переопределяют функции `print` и `var_dump`, вставляя в них элементы верстки, так что используйте просто echo или вставки типа `<?=$dost['id']?>`

Вот так, имхо, более наглядно:

```
<?php 
    $id = $dost['id'];
?>
<a
    href="index.php?page=cart&odd=<?=$id?>"
    class="count-minus"
    style="display: block; padding-left:3px; margin:10px; cursor:pointer; font: 15px sans-serif"
>
    -
</a>

<input
    disabled name="amount[<?=$id?>]"
    type="text"
    value="<?=$dost['amount'] ?>"
    class="count-input"
    maxlength="3"
    style="text-align:center; width:32px; font: 15px sans-serif; border-radius: 5px; height:22px;"
/>

<a
    href="index.php?page=cart&add=<?=$id?>"
    class="count-plus"
    style="display: block; padding-left:1px; margin:10px; cursor:pointer; font: 15px sans-serif"
>
    +
</a>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, все равно выходит код когда печать делаю...